Interactive browser request is redirected to localhost "success" page, but throws an exception afterwards
I'm in the process of implementing msal4j (version 1.17.0) into a desktop application. As its a public application I'm using the interactive browser request flow to obtain a token. I'm using the following setup (simplified) :
var application = PublicClientApplication.builder(CLIENT_ID)
          .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENANT_ID)
          .build();

var parameters =
          InteractiveRequestParameters.builder(new URI("http://localhost/"))
              .scopes(Set.of("openid"))
              .build();
      return app.acquireToken(parameters).join();

When the application is deployed to its environment, an MS edge browser window is opened
with address login.microsoftonline.com/{etc} . As I'm already logged in, the browser immediately redirects to http://localhost:{randomPort} with message:
Authentication complete. You can close the browser and return to the application.

However, at the same time an exception message is logged related to a connection exception:
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:110) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:18) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:56) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.executeRequest(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:299) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.sendInstanceDiscoveryRequest(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:249) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.doInstanceDiscoveryAndCache(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:360) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.getMetadataEntry(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:107) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.getAuthorityWithPrefNetworkHost(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:39) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:59) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:270) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:48) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:69) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.readResponseFromConnection(DefaultHttpClient.java:121) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.executeHttpGet(DefaultHttpClient.java:56) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.send(DefaultHttpClient.java:44) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequestWithRetries(HttpHelper.java:153) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:52) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.executeRequest(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:299) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.sendInstanceDiscoveryRequest(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:249) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.doInstanceDiscoveryAndCache(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:360) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.getMetadataEntry(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:107) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.getAuthorityWithPrefNetworkHost(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:39) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:59) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:270) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:48) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:69) ~[some-desktop-gui.jar:?]
    ... 8 more

Which seems strange because the server has just returned a success message stating that the authentication process has completed. Does anyone know why a connection exception is being thrown, instead of receiving a token? The connection is lost when I refresh the localhost:{randomPort} browser address, so I am assuming that the local server has been closed after having received a valid result.

To get access token, try adding User.Read permission in scopes parameter by granting API permissions as below:

In my case, I used below java code and got the access token successfully like this:
package org.example;

import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "appId";
    private static final String TENANT_ID = "tenantId";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            var app = PublicClientApplication.builder(CLIENT_ID)
                    .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENANT_ID)
                    .build();

            var parameters = InteractiveRequestParameters.builder(new URI("http://localhost/"))
                    .scopes(Set.of("openid","profile","email","User.Read"))
                    .build();

            var result = app.acquireToken(parameters).join();

            System.out.println("\nAccess Token: " + result.accessToken());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Browser:

Response:

When I decoded that token in jwt.ms website, it has scp & aud claims as below:


Thank you for your help. It wasn't related to permissions however. The application is located in a virtual machine and could only connect to the internet using a proxy server (which it did not use at the moment). The browser however could connect due to proxy config set by the administrator. Therefore, the browser would claim a success while the application could not connect to microsoftonline to trade the auth code for an access token.
